# What effect will the delay of 1 second to this year have on Unix timestamp?

Tags: unix, timestamp

Source: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-38470682

What effect will this have?

Answer (score 1):

the unix time will go from 23:59:59 to 23:59:60 and then to 00:00:00
adding one second

instead of 23:59:59 to 00:00:00